# (virtual-terminal): redundant and confusing

Tags: discussion, tags

Most questions tagged with [virtual-terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/virtual-terminal) actually refer to [virtual-console](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/virtual-console), the famous Linux feature. But some of them, such as [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/511443/term-environment-variable-not-exported-from-profile), assume such GUI terminal emulators as `gnome-terminal` and `xterm`.

First, shouldn't the [virtual-terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/virtual-terminal) tag be deprecated?
Second, where is the correct tag for programs like `gnome-terminal` and `xterm`?

---

Update: by the way, question tagged (virtual-console) have significant admixture (if not say *pollution*) of `xterm`-like stuff. It appears that many users have no idea that virtual console is a thing completely different from terminal emulators.

Comment: Id' make `virtual-console` a synonym of `virtual-terminal`.

Comment: @terdon: Virtual console is a term [unambiguously referring to virtual consoles](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/228050/how-are-virtual-consoles-related-to-traditional-computer-terminals). Virtual terminal may refer to VC as well (in the context of `console-tools`), but can be used for whatever that resembles a tty. Why should an unambiguous term redirect to an ambiguous phrase?